# In Rails and minitest, how do I name my parameters when simulating a POST create request for my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm using Rails 5 and minitest.  How do I submit parameters in minitest to simulate a POST request where my model gets created?  I have this test

```
  test "do create" do
    person = people(:one)
    score = 10
    post ratings_url, params: {rating[person_id]: person.id, rating[score]: score}

    # Verify we got the proper response
    assert_response :success
  end
```

but the above results in the error

```
localhost:myapp davea$ rails test test/controllers/ratings_controller_test.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 30344
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myapp/test/controllers/ratings_controller_test.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => (SyntaxError)
url, params: {rating[person_id]: person.id, rating[score]: score
```

The only reason I named the POST parameters "rating[person_id]" and "rating[score]" is because that's what they are named when the form is rendered in Rails as HTML.

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, I tried this in my test

```
post ratings_url, params: { rating: { person_id: person.id, score: score} }
```

and the controller looks like

```
def save(params)
  rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
  rating.user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
```

and the error I got was

```
Error:
RatingsControllerTest#test_do_create:
ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Complaining about the line

```
respond_to do |format|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash-keys in your params hash are not valid.

```
params: {rating[person_id]: person.id, rating[score]: score }
```

You can't use `rating[person_id]` and use the newer hash-syntax/ you will need to use hash-rockets here eg:

```
params: {rating[person_id] => person.id, rating[score] => score }
```

This is assuming you have a local variable called `rating` with the keys in it... 
If you aren't actually trying to get a value out of a local variable called rating... then you may need to be more detailed about your structure eg:

```
params: { rating: { person_id: person.id, score: score } }
```

of course... depending on which kind of test you are writing, you might need to not use `ratings_url` (also try it with and without the `params` key) eg:

```
post :ratings, params: { rating: { person_id: person.id, score: score } }
post :ratings, rating: { person_id: person.id, score: score }
```

Comment: I replaced the line with what you have but I still get an error that reads, "NameError: undefined local variable or method `rating' for #<RatingsControllerTest:0x00007f8696c5d748>".

Comment: Well yes - that's something I was assuming you were doing deliberately eg by having a `let` by the name of `rating` that contained test-data... it's not a bug in my answer ;) where did you get that part of the code from?

Comment: If that is not what you intended... then you may need to actually set up the params hash the way it'd come in to rails eg:  `params: { rating: { person_id: person.id, score: score} }` (though you need to bugfix that yourself if it also doesn't work... you need to tell us what structure you should be using).

Comment: I don't doubt your answers!  Anyway, I went with "post ratings_url, params: { rating: { person_id: person.id, score: score} }" (I included my controller method in the question).  I now get an error, "ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat" but I can't tell if that's because of how I'm submitting my request or some other factor.  If I should open a new quesiton, let me know.

Comment: Curious: when you actually do a real form-post... what do the params come through as? re: format (probably should be a new question, but it might be a quick fix: try just `:ratings` (instead of `ratings_url`, which might be superfluous depending on which test it's in). Does your controller support multiple formats? does it enforce one? what does your route look like for this? is the format listed as optional (in parentheses)?

Comment: params: {"rating[person_id]" => person.id, "rating[score]" => score}

Comment: Hi @TarynEast, Let me try and answer the main questions.  The form parameters come through as "rating[id]",  "rating[person_id]", and "rating[score]".  The form is POSTed via AJAX.  I'm only responding to only format in the controller -- "format.json { render json: rating, :include => {:person}, status: :created}".  Hope that fills in a few gaps.

Comment: @ZiaQamar, changed the params to what you suggested but still get the error, "ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat".

Comment: Hey @TarynEast, your original solution worked, but it needed me to add a ", as: json" at the end, making it "post ratings_url, params: { rating: { person_id: person.id, score: score} }, as: :json".

Comment: Ah cool- yes if you get a `format` error - it's usually because you need to be explicit about formats. if you happen to only ever use json, you can actually tell your controller that and then you won't need to send a format... that's there in case you want to use both html and json and switch between them. You can also tell your controller to use json by default (html is the usual default)

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe your controller is giving you a clue with `ActionController::UnknownFormat`. You should check you `logs\test.log` file to see if you can debug controller response over the test request. My hunch is that your controller is lacking some type in the `respond_to` block, or a missing template/render for a particular response type. Maybe it is posting as JS and your controller doesn't respond to that, or it is some situation where you should put a response to any type like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.any  {render :text => "I respond to any request format"}
end
```